# React Router Dom v6: automatic scroll to top not working

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

When i use React Router Dom v5 that time if i do like this way:

```
<Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
```

that time after navigate that page it automaticaly go to top by default. but if i use v6 its not working. Whenever I transition from one page to another, the second page always loads on the current location instead of the top. i cant find any updated solution. please dont give me v5 solutions.

Main.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import { router } from "./router/Routes";
import AuthProvider from "./provider/AuthProvider";
import {QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query'
import { ToastProvider } from "./provider/ToastContext";
import CheckoutProvider from "./provider/CheckoutProvider";

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <CheckoutProvider>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <ToastProvider>
            <RouterProvider router={router}>
            </RouterProvider>
          </ToastProvider>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </CheckoutProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Route.jsx (React router dom v6 to control the routes) i want to solution go to top by default when every route i hit using this v6 way.

```
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import LayoutMain from "../layout/LayoutMain";
import Login from "../pages/Authentication/Login/Login";
import Signup from "../pages/Authentication/signup/Signup";
import Home from "../pages/Home/Home";
import LayoutCategories from "../layout/LayoutCategories";
import Products from "../pages/Products/Products";
import Campaigns from "../pages/Campaigns/Campaigns";
import Coupons from "../pages/Coupons/Coupons";
import Blog from "../pages/Blog/Blog";
import AboutUs from "../pages/AboutUs/AboutUs";
import ContactUs from "../pages/ContactUs/ContactUs";
import TermsConditions from "../pages/TermsConditions/TermsConditions";
import Carts from "../pages/Carts/Carts";
import Checkout from "../pages/Checkout/Checkout";
import DashboardLayout from "../layout/DashboardLayout";
import Dashboard from "../pages/Dashboard/Dashboard";
import AddProduct from "../pages/Dashboard/AddProduct";
import AddCategory from "../pages/Dashboard/AddCategory";
import AllProducts from "../pages/Dashboard/products/AllProducts";
import EditProduct from "../pages/Dashboard/products/editProduct";
import AdminManagement from "../pages/Dashboard/AdminManagement";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import AdminRoute from "./AdminRoute";
import ProductDetails from "../components/ProductCard/ProductDetails";
import MyOrders from "../pages/Profile/OrderHistory";
import OrderManagement from "../pages/Dashboard/OrderManagement/OrderManagement";
import OrderDetails from "../pages/Dashboard/OrderManagement/OrderDetails";
import UserProfileLayout from "../layout/UserProfileLayout";
import UserProfile from "../pages/Profile/UserProfile";
import UserDashboard from "../pages/Profile/DashboardUser";
import Invoice from "../pages/Profile/Order/Invoice";
import EditProfile from "../pages/Profile/EditProfile";
import AddressBook from "../pages/Profile/AddressBook/AddressBook";
import AddAddress from "../pages/Profile/AddressBook/AddAddress";


export const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <LayoutMain/>,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <Home/>,
        },
        {
          path: "login",
          element: <Login/>,
        },
        {
          path: "signup",
          element: <Signup/>,
        },
        {
          // TODO: Need to change here
          path:"categories",
          element:<LayoutCategories/>,
          children:[
            {
              path:'biscuits',
              element: <Login/>,
            },
            {
              path:'breakfast',
              element: <Login/>,
            },
            {
              path:'baby',
              element: <Login/>,
            },
            {
              path:'organic',
              element: <Login/>,
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path:'products',
          element:<Products/>
        },
        {
          path:'details/:id',
          element:<ProductDetails/>
        },
        {
          path:'carts',
          element:<Carts/>
        },
        {
          path:'checkout',
          element:<Checkout/>
        },
        {
          path:'campaigns',
          element:<Campaigns/>
        },
        {
          path:'coupons',
          element:<Coupons/>
        },
        {
          path:'blog',
          element:<Blog/>
        },
        {
          path:'about-us',
          element:<AboutUs/>
        },
        {
          path:'contact-us',
          element:<ContactUs/>
        },
        {
          path:'terms-conditions',
          element:<TermsConditions/>
        },
        {
          path:'my-orders',
          element:<MyOrders/>
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path:"dashboard",
      element:<AdminRoute><DashboardLayout/></AdminRoute>,
      children:[
        {
          path:'',
          element: <Dashboard/>,
        },
        {
          path:'addCategory',
          element: <AddCategory/>,
        },
        {
          path:'addProduct',
          element: <AddProduct/>,
        },
        {
          path:'products',
          element: <AllProducts/>,
        },
        {
          path:'products/:id',
          element: <EditProduct/>,
        },
        {
          path:'manage-admin',
          element: <AdminManagement/>,
        },
        {
          path:'all-orders',
          element: <OrderManagement/>,
        },
        {
          path:'all-orders/details/:id',
          element: <OrderDetails/>,
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      path:"profile",
      element:<UserProfileLayout/>,
      children:[
        {
          path:'',
          element: <UserDashboard/>,
        },
        {
          path:'my-order',
          element: <MyOrders/>,
        },
        {
          path:'invoice/:id',
          element: <Invoice/>,
        },
        {
          path:'edit-profile',
          element: <EditProfile/>,
        },
        {
          path:'address',
          element: <AddressBook/>,
        },
        {
          path:'add-address',
          element: <AddAddress/>,
        },
      ]
    },
  ]);
```

i try to use react rotuer dom v6 and after going any route it will be by default go to top of the page. but its not wokring. but if i use v5 it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two way method to do that.

the first one is using the `ScrollRestoration` Component so:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import { router } from "./router/Routes";
import AuthProvider from "./provider/AuthProvider";
import {QueryClient, QueryClientProvider} from 'react-query'
import { ToastProvider } from "./provider/ToastContext";
import CheckoutProvider from "./provider/CheckoutProvider";

const queryClient = new QueryClient()

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
       <CheckoutProvider>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <ScrollRestoration>
            <ToastProvider>
              <RouterProvider router={router}>
              </RouterProvider>
            </ToastProvider>
          </ScrollRestoration>
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </CheckoutProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and the second method is using react hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useScrollToTop = () => {
  const [scrollToTop, setScrollToTop] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = () => {
      setScrollToTop(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setScrollToTop(false);
      }, 500); // delay scroll to top for half a second
    };

    window.addEventListener("popstate", handleRouteChange);
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleRouteChange);
      window.removeEventListener("hashchange", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);

  if (scrollToTop) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0); // scroll to top
  }

  return {};
};
```

and create a wrapper component to handle it:

```
import React from "react";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import useScrollToTop from "./useScrollToTop";
import { router } from "./router/Routes"

const ScrollRestoration = ({children}) => {
  useScrollToTop();

  return <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
};
```

and finally:

```
....
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
       <CheckoutProvider>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <ScrollRestoration />
            <ToastProvider />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </CheckoutProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: i try both methods still not working.